# Bootstrap Input Group with Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for creating input groups with normal text as shown in image below
[image]

How can I get input group with image and also more than 2 span text.

[image]

I am using following code for normal input group

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <input type="text" style="background-color: black; color: white" class="form-control" aria-label="You Send">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /btn-group -->
</div>
<!-- /input-group -->
```

Edit 1: 
[image: This is the requirement.]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by two-span text? Are you talking about the dropdown search suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many CSS tricks out there to embed images in the input field. Personally for me, if we're gonna be using Bootstrap, let's really use Bootstrap. And perhaps an icon pack like FontAwesome.

```css
.search-icon:before {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f002";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text border-right-0 bg-white">
    <!-- Stack overflow doesn't allow this, but if it did, I would not need
         any custom  css, just the following html only this: 
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    Instead I have to use this over here. -->
      <span class="search-icon"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control border-left-0" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

If you want to put your own custom image, you can edit the css like so:

```
.search-icon:before {
  content: url(path/to/your-image.jpg);
}
```

I'll update my answer once you clarify what you mean by two-span text.

Comment: Hi, Please check I added new image, I am looking for such 2 texts type.

Comment: @DivyamSolanki that deserves it's own questions as it's rather complicated. I do however highly recommend typeahead.js for that. It's fairly straightforward and there are enough question and answers on that topic here on stackoverflow.  https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: Thank you. Examples were helpful.